# How do structures work in Java?

Tags: java

In c++, one could simply do something like this:

```
struct GraphObject {
Color color;
double value;
String name;
};
```

However in Java, I can't simply do this, I only see creating a class just for this as an option. What I do not like about that is then I need to drag around GraphObject.java and Graph.java (since Graph will hold an ArrayList of GraphObject. Is there a way to put the object class in with Graph.java or is this simply impossible/bad practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make it a [nested class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) if appropriate for your design.

Answer (score 6):

You will want to make a **static nested class**:

```
public class Graph {
    static class GraphicObject {
        Color color;
        double value;
        String name;
    }
}
```

If you omit the `static` keyword, each instance of Graph will automatically create an instance of GraphicObject. Moreover the references will be tied together allowing synthetic access to the outer class using the `this`. Non-static (inner) classes are rarely needed and add a lot of cost to object creation.

For more information on the differences between static and non-static nested classes: http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/nested_inner_member_and_top

Answer (score 3):

You can make a class inside another class if you want to.

```
class Graph {

    class GraphicObject {
        Color color;
        double value;
        String name;

        // You can omit this, and treat it just like a struct if you want
        GraphicObject(Color c, Double b, String n) {
           // ...
        }
    }

    List<GraphicObject> myObjects();
    // other things about Graph here, as normal

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. If that's the only file you use the class in, it's not a problem. If you use it in other files, it will still work but it's not considered good practice.

Usually you'd do it as an [inner class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).

Comment: Since he probably doesn't need to use a `Graph` from within a `GraphObject`, a regular nested class is better than an inner class.

Comment: Actually you'd use a static nested class, as the nested class very rarely need access to members of the enclosing class.